# Inheritance in different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-import

I have a parent and a child class, each in their own separate file. If these two classes are in one file, my MWE works. If I split them each into their separate files, I do not know how to import each other. Here is the MWE:

```
cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from main_win import MainWin

test = MainWin()
test.click()
```

---

```
cat main_win.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sub_win import SubWin

class MainWin:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Created main window')
    def click(self):
        options = SubWin()
```

---

```
cat sub_win.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from main_win import MainWin

class SubWin(MainWin):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Created sub window')
```

If I execute `test.py` and with the circular import defined as above, I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'MainWin' from 'main_win' (/home/basil/scratch/trash/pythonInheritance/p03/main_win.py)

Edit:
There are valid comments questioning my class structure: Do I need inheritance? Could I add a super class, from which both classes above could inherit? These are very good comments and I will consider them carefully. Of course, the MWE will not be useful for you to weigh in 
 in answering these questions. For now, let's just assume that the class structure is not to be changed. How can this problem then be solved? By merging the two modules into one, or is there another way?

Comment: Why do you want `SubWin` to inherit from `MainWin`? Based on your MWE, there's no good reason for the inheritance. What do you plan to gain from it?

Comment: The issue is the circular import. You can't have modules that are importing each other. You specify this in the question, so it looks like you understand this. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, that's not obvious from the MWE. But in my real class, I want to inherit because I need access to all the dictionaries of the class MainWin.

Comment: @GalSivan: It's worth noting that Python *does* allow circular imports, and they can work OK, in some situations. They may not be a good idea (because sometimes they may break unexpectedly, and they're often a symptom of bad design), but they're not something forbidden by the language.

Comment: Have you considered having the two inherit from a common superclass which contains just those dictionaries? I'm spitballing here; I'm afraid you might have potentially made your MWE *too minimal* in this case, which is significantly better than the opposite problem.

Comment: @GalSivan I try to have parent and child classes in separate modules. In principle there is no need for that, they could go into the same module. I simply would like to do this to keep the code tidy. And to be honest, I was thinking I'm asking a trivial question.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Considering the superclass is worth a thought. I would need to think carefully about this, if this is a good idea or not, which will require some time. Thanks anyway for the suggestions already!

Comment: Yes and that's fine @pfnuesel but in that case why are you instantiating the child class in the parent?

Comment: @GalSivan Another excellent question. The SubWin is created when the user clicks on a button in the MainWin. The button is part of the parent class. But the function that is called by clicking the button does not necessarily have to be part of the parent class (again something I need to think about; I'm a slow thinker ;-)). I start to agree with what Silvio said, that my MWE might be too minimal. But it won't be easy to make it consistent without blowing it up out of proportions.

Comment: Just put them in the same module. I will say though, this design seems rather strange.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you clarify what seems strange?

Comment: Your parent class has an creates an instance of your subclass. You say "But in my real class, I want to inherit because I need access to all the dictionaries of the class MainWin." But you could use composition to achieve this, or simply pass arguments to methods. Again, maybe this is too minimal of an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular import. `main_win.py` imports `sub_win.py` which imports `main_win.py`...

To fix this and leave the code as-is, you could technically move `from sub_win import SubWin` into `MainWin.click()`. That's definitely not something I'd suggest, though, and you probably ought to go back to design and reconsider this approach to whatever it is you're attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have a circular import situation. The `main_win` module imports `sub_win`, and `sub_win` tries to import `main_win` back, but it doesn't work correctly because the `MainWin` class doesn't exist yet when the `sub_win` module tries to import it.

There are a few possible solutions.

Often the best solution is to get rid of the circular dependency between your two classes. Circular imports aren't forbidden, but a need for them often indicates sloppy design. There are many ways to fix the dependency too. In the example code, you don't need `SubWin` to inherit from `MainWin` at all, so you could just drop the inheritance. If they do need to share some common code or information, maybe they should both inherit it from a common ancestor (e.g. `Window`), where that shared stuff can go. Another option would make the two classes unrelated, but have `MainWin` pass the info `SubWin` needs to its constructor (e.g. `options = SubWin(some_data)`).

Another option might be to defer the import of `sub_win` to after `MainWin` exists in the `main_win` namespace. You can do this by moving the `from sub_win import SubWin` statement somewhere further down in the code. It could either remain at the module's top level somewhere below the definition of `MainWin`, or it could be put right inside of the `click` method, where it is used (so it would be a local variable in the function, rather than a global).

A final idea is to put your classes in the same module so you don't need the import statements at all. If your two classes are as tightly coupled as your current design suggests, then there's definitely no reason to separate them out into separate modules. Python is very different from some other programming languages (like Java) where the default is for every class to have its own source file. Python projects often feature large modules with many classes and global functions in them. You only need to split your modules up if they get so large that you regularly find yourself using part of their code without needing other parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. I do not know why you got downvoted.